# Django - Make query to join three tables with prefetch_related

Tags: python, django, orm

I am using Django 1.11. I have three tables.

```
A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

B(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    a = models.ForeignKey(A, related_name='b')

D(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
```

Is it possible to get all D's with their corresponding rows from B using prefetch related? I want to refer fields in D model and compare with B model while making that prefetch query. May be something like this:

```
D.objects.all().select_related(
         'a'
         ).prefetch_related(Prefetch(
                                    'a__b',
                                    queryset=B.objects.filter(name=F('d__name'))
                                    ))
```

Comment: What you are doing is correct.

Comment: It is not able to find `d` inside `B`. So I think I need to change something there.

Comment: But you can directly search into B for `name='abc'` as  the same filter you applied at D.

Comment: try like `D.objects.prefetch_related('a__b').filter(name='abc', a__b__name='abc')`

Comment: Problem with this one is that it will still give me all `b` related to `a`. I want to get rows of `B` which matched with that condition. `D.objects.prefetch_related('a__b').filter(a__b__name=F('name'))` - This will return all D and also all `b` related to `a` because prefetch is not filtered (Correct me if i am wrong).  I have edited my question for better understanding of my problem.